# Passing value by reference

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Can someone explain what this is?

```
struct p{
    int x;
    int y;
    struct p *ptr;
};
```

I can't understand the line where we again write `struct p`.

Comment: Yes self referential structure...

Comment: Are you aware of pointers? If yes, please clarify what more exactly is puzzling you? If no, what you need is a tutorial on pointers and I feel with you, there is some rough road ahead.

Comment: what is self refrential structure and what is it purpose??

Comment: You may want to fix the title to this question - the question does not refer to "_passing_" anything.  It is simply a structure definition.

Comment: @someone : Now you have a name for it you can Google it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't understand the line where we again write struct p

In the structure `p` declaration, you have:

```
struct p *ptr;
```

where `ptr` is a pointer which can point to address of `struct p` type structure which makes `struct p` a self-referential structure.

**A self-referential structure is a structure in which one of its members is a pointer to the structure itself.**

Let consider one example:

Say you have two variable `a` and `b` of type `struct p`:

```
    struct p a;
    struct p b;
```

Initialize the members of `a` and `b`:

```
    a.x = 1;
    a.y = 2;
    a.ptr = NULL;
    b.x = 3;
    b.y = 4;
    b.ptr = NULL;
```

After this, the in-memory view of `a` and `b` will be something like this:

```
a:
  x   y   ptr
+-------------+
| 1 | 2 | NULL|
+-------------+

b:
  x   y   ptr
+-------------+
| 3 | 4 | NULL|
+-------------+
```

The `struct p` is self-referential structure as one of its member variable `ptr` pointer can point to `struct p` type. Lets assign address of `b` to `ptr` of `a`:

```
a.ptr = &b; //assigning address of structure b to pointer a.ptr
```

It will look like:

```
a
+------------+
| 1 | 2 |  --|----¬
+------------+    |
                  |
               b  V
               +-------------+
               | 3 | 4 | NULL|
               +-------------+
```

Now, you can access the member of structure `b` with `a.ptr`, like this:

```
printf ("b.x : %d, a.ptr->x : %d\n", b.x, a.ptr->x);
```

Its output:

```
b.x : 3, a.ptr->x : 3
```

Self-Referential structures are one of the most useful features that allow you to create data structures that contain references to data of the same type as themselves. I would suggest you to try to implement `Linked List` data structure using C language which will give you a much better understanding of self-referential structure.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a `struct p` that contains a *pointer* to a `struct p`.

It may be used for example, to create a *linked list* of `struct p` objects, where one `struct p` contains a pointer to the next as a means of creating a sequence of variable length as opposed to an array that is of fixed length, and avoiding potentially expensive `realloc` calls that a variable length contiguous dynamic *vector* of `struct p` objects might require.

It may also used for more complex data structures such as the *doubly linked list* and *binary serach tree* for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is a self referential structure. In the last line you declare a pointer `ptr` which points to the structure `struct p`.

A helpful resource for getting along with pointers and structures in C may be https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-structures-pointers